# Object auto detect the datatype and convert to the datatype I need

Tags: c#

I have a variable returns datatype as `Object`. Sometimes, it returns `datetime`, sometimes return `bool` etc.

But I don't want to use `if ... else` statement to list out all possibility and convert to the right datatype.

Any way to use `convert.tostring(xxx)` , `convert.toboolean(xxx)`?

Comment: I can't imagine how would you use something like that. Could add an example code showing that?

Comment: But how you would use the result of the conversion? If you want to have compile time support, you have to assign it to proper variable type on way or another... So what is the purpose of such conversion?

Comment: After the conversion you mut store the value in a variable, what is the type of this variable?

Comment: @pravprab `var` is used to implicitly type a variable, not convert it.

Comment: @pravprab Yes, you could, and `var` would then resolve to `object`. Then what would you do?

Comment: @pravprab: `var` does compile-time type inference. If the method returns `object`, `var` will infer `object`. They *could* perhaps use `dynamic`, but I've never used it, so I don't know how overload resolution works with it.

Comment: ok. i have created a custom class schema, before upload to my mysqlcommand, the value need to be return to the right datatype.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to investigate the [Convert.ChangeType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Convert_methods%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) methods in the [Convert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Convert%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class.

Here's a little example that might help

```
namespace UnitTest
{
    using System;

    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ConvertToType(DateTime.Now).GetType().Name);
            Console.WriteLine(ConvertToType<Guid>(Guid.NewGuid()).GetType().Name);
            Console.Read();
        }

        public static dynamic ConvertToType(object obj)
        {
            //If you're unsure of the type you want to return.
            return Convert.ChangeType(obj, obj.GetType());
        }

        public static T ConvertToType<T>(object obj)
        {
            //If you definitely know the type you want to return.
            return (T)Convert.ChangeType(obj, typeof(T));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using dynamic object concept.

[dynamic object concept](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.dynamicobject%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: I believe OP is not sure of C# typing concepts so introducing dynamic object will only harm this knowledge more...

Comment: i think can't. because the variable that i going to assign is fixed datatype, but the value going to assign is object. i need to convert it to the right datatype before really can assign into it.

Answer (score 0):

But i think you simply can't do it, you could use reflection to write a method:

```
var test = variable.ConvertIt();
```

Where ConvertIt, with reflection, can cast the variable at runtime and return a dynamic. But now how do you use test variable?

Sorry for my bad bad bad english.

Comment: thanks for your reply. but i still can't get it on how is the coding looks like if an object to have extra function on it. can you show me?

Comment: You can enumerate all methods of an Object type by your_type.GetMethods(BindingFlags....ecc)

Answer (score 0):

This might look peculiar, but your problem (do not want to use `if-else`) is peculiar at first place. This doesn't seem possible any other way. Data types were created because you cannot just use a variable for processing all kinds of data. It is a problem for not only the programmer but the compiler too.

```
try
{
    int a = convert.toint32(x);
    // Process a;
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    try
    {
        string b = convert.tostring(x);
        //Process b;
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        // and so on...
    }
}
```

Also, this uses `Convert.To__`, as you wanted.